# How to improve highcharts rendering in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, highcharts, react-table

I am trying to use Solid gauge charts in my React application. I am displaying the table using react-table package. It is working without any issue. I am able to add a solid gauge chart as a row data. When I sort the table column, it takes time to sort the table with a solid gauge chart. The sorting happens on integer values between 0 to 100. The results are as below :

Table info:

- no of rows - can be different based on the data
- no of columns - 5 (1 column for the title, 4 columns for solid gauge chart)
- animation - off
- chart type - 360 degrees (full circle)

No of records:  sorting Time

- 3                :  < 1 seconds
- 10               :  2-3 seconds
- 60               :  10-12 seconds

How can I reduce the sorting time? Do I need to use boost module from highcharts?

Code:

```js
class SolidGaugeCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      componentDom: "",
      redirect: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    const options = {
      chart: {
        type: "solidgauge",
        backgroundColor: "#212121",
        height: 1 * 70 + "%"
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
        pointFormat: 
          '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">           {this.props.tooltipTitle} </td>' +
            '<td style="text-align: center"><b>{point.y} %</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        valueDecimals: 2
        },
      title: {
        text: this.props.title,
        style: {
          color: "#fff",
          backgroundColor: "#282828"
        }
      },
      pane: {
        center: ["50%", "50%"],
        size: "100%",
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: {
          innerRadius: "80%",
          outerRadius: "100%",
          shape: "arc"
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        stops: [
          [0.0, "#FF0000"], 
          [0.64, "#FF0000"], 
          [0.65, "#FFFF00"], 
          [0.79, "#FFFF00"], 
          [0.80, "#32CD32"], 
          [0.99, "#32CD32"]
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
          y: -70
        },
        labels: {
          enabled: false,
          y: 10
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
          innerRadius: "80%",
          dataLabels: {
            y: -20,
            color: "#fff",
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true,
            format:
              '<div style="text-align:center">' +
              '<span style="font-size:20px">{y}%</span><br/>' +
              "</div>"
          }
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          animation: false,
          data: [this.props.data]
        }
      ]
    };
    return (
      <div>
        {/* {this.props.data} */}
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling this component inside react-table.

Example scenario,

I want to display 50 rows. Each row has 4 solid gauge charts. In total, SolidGaugeCard component will be mounted 50x4 = 200 times to render entire table. The problem is that the table gets render only after all the rows have called the SolidGaugeCard component.

Is there any way that i can render rows dynamically? I mean as soon as the 1st row has called SolidGaugeCard component 4 times, render that row. And keep following for the rest of the table. In this way, there will not be any dead screen time.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with a sample data, which I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I have added a code of chart component.

Comment: To be honest - it's hard to say what could help with those informations which you have provided. Maybe destroying all charts and render them after sorting will help. Or implementing some lazy loading. It will be easier to say more if you will prepare a demo which will show exactly the issue.